# How do I use on method to get the sizes of two different-sized arrayslists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm new to Java and I want to use one method, getCount, to get the sizes of two arraylists that are not the same size. What code could I use so that I can call, for example, examp1.getCount and examp2.getCount, and get the two different sizes?

Comment: Please post whatever you've tried at your end.

Comment: examp2.size();.................
http://www.java67.com/2016/07/how-to-find-length-size-of-arraylist-in-java.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is frankly as basic a question as it gets, and google could have helped you with this easily. Here's your entire method if you want to design your own.

```
public static int getCount(ArrayList A){
        return A.size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> In your method, use `.size()` to get the sizes of the two ArrayLists
>   and store the sizes in the array and then `return` that array.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you create 2 lists li1 and li2 then :
package output;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CalculateLength {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> li1= new ArrayList<>();
        li1.add(1);
        li1.add(2);
        getCount(li1);
        List<Integer> li2= new ArrayList<>();
        li2.add(1);
        li2.add(2);
        li2.add(3);
        li2.add(4);
        getCount(li2);
    }

    public static int getCount(List list) {
        System.out.println("LEngth = " + list.size());
        return list.size();
    }
}
```